# Ideal $I$ contained in a non-trivial ideal and quotient algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I read, in Tikhomirov's appendix to Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа*, that *in order that the ideal $I$ be contained in a non-trivial ideal $I'\subset X$, it is necessary and sufficient that the algebra $X/I$ has a non-trivial ideal*.

The theorem is stated in the context of commutative Banach (unitary) algebras, but the proof ([p. 521 here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) seems to show that it is valid for any commutative algebra defined as a linear space where a commutative, associative and distributive (with respect to the addition) multiplication is defined such that $\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{K}\quad \alpha(xy)=(\alpha x)y=x(\alpha y)$.

In any case, whether it concerns only commutative Banach unitary algebras or commutative algebras as defined above, I think we must intend *contained* as *properly contained*. Am I right? Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Lemma 2 (p 521) only necessity is demonstrated, and the demonstration does no more than point to the general structure theorem for arbitrary commutative rings - that for a ring $A$ and an ideal $I$ the ideals over $I$ in $A$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the ideals of $A/I$.

the answer to your question is, therefore, yes.

Comment: $\infty$ thanks!!!